# switch statement not changing a variable

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I have a switch statement that goes as follows:

```
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
            case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                running = false;
                break;
            case SDLK_w:
                y -= 10;
                std::cout << "pressed" << std::endl;
                std::cout << y << std::endl;
            case SDLK_s:
                y += 10;
            }
```

when i run this program, press w and look in the console pressed is displayed and so is the value of y but however much i press w variable y will not change.

s however works just fine.

Comment: you miss a `break` just before `case SDLK_s:`

Comment: y-=10  and y+=10   are getting executed and therefore y will not change.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: @NathanOliver Also, extending the "printf debugging" to `SDLK_s` case would have also revealed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed a break before starting the new case
consider the below skeleton

```
 switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
   case SDLK_ESCAPE:
    running = false;
    break;
   case SDLK_w:
    y -= 10;
    std::cout << "pressed" << std::endl;
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
    break;
   case SDLK_s:
    y += 10;
    break;
   }
```

Comment: Simple typos like this should be closed and not answered.